# Putting image as submit button Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I can't seem to find a way to put image as submit button in blade, is there a way to do this?

```
 {!! Form::submit('Search', array('class'=>'btn')) !!}
```

Comment: There is no method to do this. You need to write the HTML manually.

Comment: @Fiete Yes, there is. `Form::input('image')`.

Comment: @ceejayoz learning never stops. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`Form::input` should do the trick:

```
{!! Form::input('image', 'Search', array('class'=>'btn', 'src' => '...')) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the submit with pure html instead of laravelcollective like that

```
<input type="image" src="sourse for image" width="48" height="48" alt="Submit" />
```

Comment: True, and for a submit button you're not losing any functionality around old input values by doing this either. +1

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel Collective version 6.2 the solution  This small example shows the sending of a variable by means of a button with an image (src='../path/to/file) using the 'submit' passing as parameters the dimensions of the button (30,30).

Note: var_to_send can have a string like $ansver - > 'Hello World' or another value and it will pass it from the controller and it will print it.

// new.blade.php

{!! Form::open([ 'action'=> 'StorageController@save', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true]) !!}

```
{!! Form::hidden('var_to_send', $answer) !!}

{!! Form::image(url('../img/A.png'), 'submit', ['width' => '30',  'height' => '30'])  !!}
```

{!! Form::close() !!}

//  StorageController.php

class StorageController extends Controller
{

public function save(Request $request)
{

return $request->input('var_to_send');

}

}

// route wep.php

Route::post('storage/create', 'StorageController@save');